# Execute Javascript on new HTML-Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, window

I have two HTML-Pages (A.html and B.html). On Page A there is a button called "UploadButton"

```
<input id="UploadButton" type="button" value="Dateien auswählen" />
```

This is connected to some jQuery code

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $().SPServices({
            operation: "GetList",
            listName: "Doc",
            async: false,
            completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                id = $(xData.responseXML).find("List").attr("ID");
            }
        });

        reference = "./_layouts/Upload.aspx?List=" + id + "&amp;RootFolder=";

        $('#UploadButton').click(function (event) {
            NewItem2(event, reference);
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

So far so good... The Button or a little closer the NewItem2() method open up a new HTML Page (Page B). On page B there is an anchor I want to click.

So my question is, how can I click an anchor on page B with a Script from page A. Is there a possibility to do that? I don´t know how to do that properly.

The NewItem2() is not written through my hands, so I cant tell you whats happening in there. I tried to find something via Google or in the forum but I don´t know how to call my problem so I found nothing, sorry.

Thankls for all effort!

Comment: You should post a code of `NewItem2`, I suppose. That way it will be much easier to give an aswer which is really like you need.

Comment: As I said in my question... The method wasn´t written through my hands so I can´t give you the code, because I don´t have it.

Comment: And you have no access to other JS files? And can't open that web page in browser and use developer tools to get its code from there? If so, I do not think it will be possible to help you somehow.

Comment: hey FAngle... Thanks for your effort. I solved the problem on my own. Yes, there is access to the JS files but the code isn´t that simple. It´s hard to get through the lines and connect one point with another - code is written by Microsoft ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Simple - You cant´t use Page A`s scriptvariables on Page B.

When you just want to click an HTML anchor, why don´t you simply add #anchorname to your reference to create the same effect?

The easiest way to submit information between pages is the [QueryString](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). 
Just pass the ID of the control which you want to click and write some javascript to read the [QueryString](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) and execute the .click().

Comment: Sorry... That wont work. The NewItem2() won´t work properly that way.

Answer (score 0):

Should use external JavaScript file by copying your JavaScript/jQuery code to the onther file and set extencion .js in last include your this this file in both page (A.html and B.html) as shown below.

```
<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript" SRC="|YOUR FILE NAME|" />
```

So you does not need to specify different methods for different pages where same type of action are being done.

Answer (score 0):

If `window.open` is used to open that new window, than you can take a refference to that window like this:

```
var newWindow = window.open("...new window url here...");
```

and than, using `newWindow` you can access its content:

```
newWindow.$("#anchore_to_click").click()
```

(assuming jquery is available there too)